# How to loop over files with multiple conditions in a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script that does things to files with a certain extension in the following format:

for %%f in (*.xxx) do (

...

...

)

How, using the same for loop (I don't want to write one for each filetype as there are many) would I go about making this work for filetypes .xxx, .yyy and .zzz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the help, `for` accepts one or more files in set:

> ```
> Runs a specified command for each file in a set of files.
>
> FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]
>
>   %variable  Specifies a single letter replaceable parameter.
>   (set)      Specifies a set of one or more files.  Wildcards may be used.
>   command    Specifies the command to carry out for each file.
>   command-parameters
>              Specifies parameters or switches for the specified command.
>
> [...]
> ```

Therefore, you can do it like this:

```
for %%f in (*.xxx *.yyy *.zzz) do (

    rem (your commands here)

)
```